# html canvas resolution issue with overlaying boxes

Tags: html, canvas, fill

I have noticed issues with drawing one box over another. As requested, here is the code, but in greater detail

```
function draw(x,y,w,h,c){
 ctx.fillStyle=c;
 ctx.strokeStyle=c;
 ctx.lineWidth=1;
 ctx.globalAlpha=1.0;
 ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
}

function Rectangle(x,y,w,h,c){
 this.x=x;
 this.y=y;
 this.w=w;
 this.h=h;
 this.c=c;
 this.draw=draw;

 this.onMouseEnter=function(){
  this.c='rgb(0,0,0)';   //black
  this.draw();
 }

this.onMouseLeave=function(){
 this.c='rgb(255,255,255)';   //white
 this.draw();
 }
}
box=new Rectangle(10,10,110,110,'rgb(255,255,255)');  //black box at
```

At rest the box is white, but on hover, it turns black. However, there is still a white border. I am pretty sure this is not a calculation error on my part as I am changing the color, not the dimensions. I have also noticed this problem occurring in most of my other onHover functions.

Why does HTML have these problems with drawing over other objects.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the code that does the drawing?  What browser version are you testing with?

Comment: Could you also show your drawing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can often happen if you're creating the rect with non-int values.  See http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/9tZTy/

If you change the numbers to non-integers (e.g. 25.5), you'll see that the box has a red "glow" around it when you click on the canvas.

Simple solution is to floor every value you pass to fillRect:

```
ctx.fillRect(x1 << 0, y1 << 0, x2 << 0, y2 << 0);
```

[edit]

Your example seems to be using ints, so if you still see the issue in my demo, call clearRect() first.

Comment: I didn't put up all the code because I am using large classes. For example, this particular rectangle would be initialized to be 92% of the canvas height. Also I cant use clearRect because I have complex shapes and images pretty much all over the place. I thought about creating a buffer region around all my shapes, but gave up after realising that I would need knowledge of what's behind my object

Comment: in that case, hopefully just floor'ing the values will work.  If it doesn't, can you let me know what browser you're using?

Comment: What does `<<` have to do with flooring values? It is listed as a bitwise shift, which I would assume is unary.

Comment: oh, sorry.  It's my shorthand for flooring int's.  For any int < 2^32, it's identical to Math.floor(num) but much, much faster.  Yes, it's a bitwise shift but there's an implicit cast-to-int in it.

Comment: @cwolves: it definitely has solved the immediate problem. However, as I have dozens of classes, I will have to carefully apply this solution to them too. Thank You.

Comment: you could replace fillRect with a new function that does this :)

Comment: @cwolves I'll just do that then since I already have a separate class for all draw related functions...Seems to work like a charm. Thanks